# Improving on a visual fitting process for fecundity data

Tags: r

I can find little information out there on this subject, but I wish to fit Pearson I curves to fecundity data. The data and solution below is lifted from a book (Applied demography for biologists, Carey 1993). I wish to automate this process using maximum likelihood, then apply goodness of fit tests. Currently it is a purely a visual/ trial and error exercise fitting the curve to the data. I've not had success with the PearsonDS package or other methods such as fitdist.

```
#par(mar=c(5,5,3,4),cex=1.2)
###taken from Carey 1993,egg/fem/day
egg=c(0,0,0,2.32,17.82,36.34,80.77,68.49,75.00,82.12,75.16,65.20,56.04,43.28,53.52,49.50,27.85,37.62,28.53,30.34,29.57,48.17,27.25,25.37,28.66,13.00,17.13,8,12.70,10.25,4)


##Vector for days,x
d=seq(from=0,to=length(med)-1)

###Parameters for the Pearson I function
a1=.55
a2=34
m1=1.46
m2=3

##The Pearson function  
y=2.8
pearI=function(pearson)
    {
    y*((1+d/a1)^m1)*((1-d/a2)^m2)
    }   

pr2=(pearI(egg))    
##
plot(egg,main=expression(bold(
           paste("Pearson Type I function fitted to ", M[x]))), 
     xlab="Age (days)",ylab="Eggs/fem", pch=16,cex.lab=1.4)
#lines(egg,col="red")
lines(pr2,type="b",col="blue",pch=16, cex=1.3)
```

Comment: I think maybe there are some typos in your code (`pearI` isn't using it's only argument? Shouldn't all the parameters be arguments too)? But I think what you're looking for is `nls`.

Comment: Need to define `med` and probably want to change the argument list in `pearI` to be "x" rather than "pearson"